# Is every subgroup of a group generated by some elements of the original group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The main question is already in the title but let me write it again.
Let $G$ be a group and $H$ its subgroup. Is $H$ necessarily generated by some elements of $G$?

My intuition tells me this is obvious but I may have missed something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$H$ is generated by the elements of $H$ (and, perhaps, smaller generating sets too).  All elements of $H$ are also elements of $G$.  Hence the answer is "yes".

Answer (score 1):

Since $H\subseteq G$, all generators of $H$ must lie in $G$. So the answer is yes. More formally, let $S\subseteq H$ be a set of generatros of $H$. Then
$$
S\subseteq H\subseteq G.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Fun fact that looks at the other side: if $H$ is a proper subgroup of $G$, then all the elements *outside* $H$ generate the whole of $G$: $\langle G - H \rangle = G$.

Comment: Are you sure? Let's take $\mathbb{Z}_2^2$, $\mathbb{Z} \times \{0\}$ is a proper subgroup and its complement doesn't generate the original group.

Comment: It does! Look carefully!

Comment: I wrote it down after I posted the comment and saw the mistake, fun fact indeed!

Comment: Can you prove it?